# zip using batch file

Tags: batch-file, zip

I need to make a condition for unzipping a file using batch.

The method is as follows:
If dummy=1, the batch will unzip an xlsx file to a particular folder, else , it will copy another xlsx file directly to that folder.

my code is as follows:

```
set dummy=1

If %dummy% EQU 1 (
SET CHEMIN=C:\file_to_unzip
cd %CHEMIN%
for /f %%j in ('dir /b %CHEMIN%\*.zip') do (
C:\PROGRA~1\WinZip\Winzip32 -min -e -o -j %CHEMIN%\%%j %CHEMIN%
) 
COPY "C:\file_to_unzip\*.xlsx" "C:\destination" 
) else (
COPY "C:\file_to_copy\*.xlsx" "C:\destination"
)
```

The problem is that without the IF condition, the unzip command will work properly. But once the IF condition is included, the cmd will say that the zip file cannot be found. I am not sure what causes this issue and how to solve this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add a `pause` statement at the end of this script OR run this script from `cmd.exe` with `@echo off` removed from start. This will help you examine if any intermediate command is failing. & whether commands are indeed getting arguments as per your expectations. Also, put `pwd` & `dir /b %CHEMIN%\*.zip` just after cd command, purely for debugging purpose.

Comment: thanks. I tried the echo off, but the output is quite messy, nevertheless, i could get the error message from the cmd. However, sometimes the batch just exit the cmd completely without leaving any message (i guess it's because of syntax error?), which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: 'i guess it's because of syntax error": That's why I am asking you to run from cmd.exe, instead of double clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have delayed expansion enabled? `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
With your example code above, the failure will occur due to the CHEMIN variable being set within the if statement. If a variable is set within a parentheses scope, the new value set for that variable will not be available until the all the sub scopes have ended. Run the following script to see what I mean:

```
@echo off
set "xValue=1"
echo.%xValue%
if 1 EQU 1 (
    set "xValue=2"
    echo.%xValue%
    echo.!xValue!
)
```

If delayed expansion is disabled (which it is by default), the results will be

```
1
1
1
```

if enabled, add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the beginning

```
1
1
2
```

Try your script as follows.  To use

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set dummy=1

If %dummy% EQU 1 (
    SET CHEMIN=C:\file_to_unzip
    cd !CHEMIN!
    for /f %%j in ('dir /b !CHEMIN!\*.zip') do (
        C:\PROGRA~1\WinZip\Winzip32 -min -e -o -j !CHEMIN!\%%j !CHEMIN!
    )
    COPY "C:\file_to_unzip\*.xlsx" "C:\destination" 
) else (
    COPY "C:\file_to_copy\*.xlsx" "C:\destination"
)
```

Another solution would be to just move the `set CHEMIN=C:\file_to_unzip` line outside of the if statement.

Comment: Thanks. It works after i add the delayedexpansion and the !CHEMIN!. so my guess is that under delayedexpansion, the !CHEMIN! will force the CHEMIN expression to be evaluated immediately?